# In how many ways can $5$ exams be scheduled in $40$ class days so that any two exams are at least $3$ class days apart?

Tags: combinatorics

With a total of $40$ days, a teacher has to give $5$ exams on these days, but any two of these exams must be $≥ 3$ class days apart (for example, if there is an exam on Day $14$, then there can be no exam on Day $15$ or Day $16$, but an exam on Day $17$ is alright). How many ways can the teacher do this?

My initial thought without taking into account for the $≥ 3$ days is that there are ${40 \choose 5}$ ways but not sure how to take in the 3 days into account, I'm guessing it's maybe ${40 \choose 5}$ minus something

Comment: You can just remove $8$ days from the month and count all possible combinations of $5$ from $32$ — then add the removed $8$ days back by inserting $2$ days in each of $4$ spans between consecutive exams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d_0$ denote the number of days before the first exam.

Let $d_1$ denote the number of days after the $1$-st exam and before the $2$-nd exam.

et cetera, ending with:

Let $d_4$ denote the number of days after the $4$-th exam and before the $5$-th exam.

Let $d_5$ denote the number of days after the $5$-th exam.

Then to be found is the number of sums: $$d_0+d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5=40-5=35$$where the $d_i$ are nonnegative integers, and under the extra condition that $d_i\geq2$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

This number equals the number of sums: $$e_0+e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4+e_5=35-4\times2=27$$where the $e_i$ are nonnegative integers (do you see why?).

This can solved by means of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) resulting in:$$\binom{27+5}{5}=\binom{32}5$$

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved with concept of integral solutions. 
Let the teacher arranges an exam with gaps $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ and $a_6$. So first exam is after $a_1$ days from first day. That is on $a_1+1$ th day. Then next exam is on $(a_1+1)+(a_2+1)$th day and so on.
So the constraints are $a_1,a_6 \ge 0$ and $a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5 \ge 2$. And their sum should be $40-5=35$.
Now you can frame an equation:
$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6= 35$
You can write each $a_2,a_3,a_4and a_5$ as $e_2+2,e_3+2,e_4+2,e_5+2$ such that $e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5 \ge 0$ . So you get a new equation:
$a_1+e_2+e_3+e_4+e_5+a_6=27$
The number of integral solutions of this equation, each $\ge 0$ is given by $C^{32}_5$ which is the required answer